# How to export sf data to Spark by sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, r-sf, sparklyr

I need to execute the `st_join` function as shown below. I am trying to use the `sparklyr` package because the data is very large, and my computer does not run. However, I am unable to export spatial objects to Spark, to use them in `st_join`. The most I was able to do was export my 'mod' and 'bio' data as csv to Spark, but even so I can't transform them into spatial data with the `st_as_sf` function. Would anyone know a tip for using st_join efficiently in my case by `sparklyr`?

```
library(sf)

mod <- readRDS("all_41.rds")
mod$cod <- 1:nrow(mod)
points_sf = st_as_sf(mod, coords = c("mun_lon", "mun_lat"), crs = 4326, agr = "constant",na.fail =F)
bio <- sf::st_read("lm_bioma_250.shp")
biomes_sf <- st_transform(bio, 4326)
result2 <- as.data.frame(st_join(points_sf, biomes_sf, join = st_intersects))
```